# I get that there is no skbio module even though scikit-bio is successfully installed

Tags: python, skbio

I'm on mac, OS Catalina, and I run Python 3.8. I have installed scikit-bio successfully:

[image]

But I try the test, I get that there is no module named skbio:

[image]

And what I guess is expected is that when I call skbio on jupyter, I get the same message:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you use pip to install scikit-bio? And, are you using conda to setup your environment? Would be worth checking by activating the conda environment and running `which pip` (should be somewhere in your conda directory). Try running `conda install scikit-bio`.

Comment: Thank you @ElDeveloper. Does "conda" comes with python3? When I run "where conda" in my terminal, I get "conda not found". But if I ask "where python3", I get "python3: aliased to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/anaconda3/bin/python" and "/usr/local/bin/python3", so there is an anaconda environment, isn't there? In the case it's there but not activated I tried "conda activate /usr/local/bin/python3" and I got "zsh: command not found: conda".

Answer (score 0):

First run this cell and after installation you can use the package:

```
pip install scikit-bio
```